# Extra argument error (I don't understand it)

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swift2

My previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228368/i-dont-understand-this-error-extra-argument-error-in-call?noredirect=1#comment63957616_38228368

I have tried to change my code from

```
        var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)
```

to

```
        var urlData: NSData?

        do {
            urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response){
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

but I still get an error saying "Extra argument 'returnResponse' in call". Could someone help me fix this? I'm also getting "Extra argument 'error' in call" on this line

```
    let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary
```

Comment: just remove `error: &error` parameter

Comment: Remove the `{}` at the end of the `sendSynchronousRequest` call

Comment: Side note: `sendSynchronousRequest` is deprecated. Use `NSURLSession` and an asynchronous task.

Comment: @vadian how would I change it to NSURLSession? I'm relatively new to swift.

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use this modern API

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in
  if error != nil {
    print(error!)
  } else {
    do {
      let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:[]) as! [String:AnyObject]
      print(jsonData)
      // parse jsonData here and then update the UI
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
  }
}.resume()
```

In Swift don't use Foundation collection types (`NSArray`, `NSDictionary`) unless you have absolutely no choice.

Answer (score 1):

**Try Declare as below may it helps you**

```
let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as NSDictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty faulty. You are using `error: &error` argument which is not necessary and remove `{}`  at the end of the `sendSynchronousRequest`.
BTW `sendSynchronousRequest` is deprecated, use `NSURLSession`

So the code should look like this:

```
let jsonData:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary
```

Comment: I ended up with this error: call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

Comment: @GeorgeWisten So listen to the error and use `try`. Read the language guide on error handling.